# Protect Sheet when condition is met by change (Google Sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, accessibility, protected

There is a case where test is given to a certain student. The student can only work with the answer for the test before a given period.

Here is the sample case:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xS3SMrSh2vHCb-ShP96IzzKQGRXYK7ACKO0Ua4_OHOY/edit?usp=sharing

1. Sheet1!A:A is where the questions are given
2. Sheet1!B:B is where the answer must be written by the student
3. Sheet2!A1 is the condition to protect or unprotect Sheet1. When the date is after 15th, this cell become 1, otherwise it stays 0. This cell change automatically since it contains TODAY() formula.
4. When Sheet2!A1 change into 1, Sheet1!A:B need to be protected from editing by anyone unless the owner of the file

Is it possible to automatically protect sheet or range (in the example case is Sheet1!A:B) when a condition met?

For instance, if cell A1 in Sheet2 is 0, then Sheet1 is protected from being edited by anyone (excluding me). If cell A1 in Sheet2 is no 0, then Sheet1 is not locked anymore.

Is there any formula or google sheet script that can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually implement that on **Sheet** using **Time Driven Trigger** of Apps Script. Time Driven Trigger executes at a particular time. In your case, you have to use **Month timer** as **Type of time based trigger**. **Month timer** has `day of month` and `time of day` properties which you can set to determine which day and time the script will run.

### Example:

Follow these steps:

1. *Copy and paste the code below to your code editor and save.*

```
function testFunc(){
    var e = {
    'day-of-month':16
    }
    lockUnlockSheet(e)
}


function lockUnlockSheet(e) {
    var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    if (e['day-of-month'] >= 16) {
    var protection = sheet1.protect().setDescription("Protect Sheet1");
    var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
    protection.addEditor(me);
    protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
    if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
    }
    } else {
    sheet1.protect().remove();
    }
}
```

2. Once you paste the code, click **Save**
3. Go to the **Triggers** tab in your editor (Located on the left side of the editor with alarm clock symbol)
4. Click **Add Trigger**
5. Copy the configuration of the trigger below (You should have 2 triggers generated)

[image]

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

All set now. But to test the function, we need the help of another function to mimic the behavior of Trigger. This is where we use the `testFunc()`.

In your editor click the dropdown besides the **Debug** button and change it to **testFunc** then Click **Run**.

If you set the value of `day-of-month` to 16-31, it will lock the Sheet1.

[image]

If you change it to 1 - 15 it will unlock it.

[image]

Note: Installable triggers always run under the account of the person who created them. The `getEffectiveUser()` is always you.

---

### Update: Using onEdit Trigger

**Code:**

```
function onEditLock(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (range.getA1Notation() == "A1" && sheet.getName() == "Sheet2") {
    if (e.value == 1) {
      var protection = sheet1.protect().setDescription("Protect Sheet1");
      var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
      protection.addEditor(me);
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    } else if(e.value == 0) {
      sheet1.protect().remove();
    }
  }
}
```

**Trigger Setup:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Note: onEdit() only runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.**

### References:

- [Time-driven events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events)
- [onEdit events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Class Protection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: The suggestion works but it lacks one thing. What I need is a method to lock Sheet1 by a condition that is met in Sheet2!A1. As long as Sheet2!A1 is 0, then Sheet1 is unlocked. On the other han, when Sheet2!A1 is 1, then Sheet1 is locked. Sheet2!A1 trigger can be anything (such as me manually change the number) aside from time trigger value. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, It is possible with onEdit() Trigger. I will add an onEdit() sample on my answer above.

Comment: @RandyAdikara - I updated my answer above. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Great! It works! Thanks! I am going to mark your answer as accepted solution to solve the problem.

One more thing, it is a rather bit out of this case. Is it possible to automatically lock / unlock Sheet1 if value at Sheet2!A1 is imported from another google sheet file? So, I dont need to open and edit all of the students' file. So it only requires me to edit 1 master file then the value is imported via IMPORTRANGE to each students' file at Sheet2!A1. Maybe, the trigger is now not "on edit" but "on change". If possible, can you help on this?

Comment: @RandyAdikara - Thank you for accepting my answer. Regarding your new concern, I would prefer you create another post with detailed information so that the community can have a better understanding of your problem. This will also give you a better chance of getting good answers.